# "user is not in the sudoers file" despite user belonging to group wheel

Tags: linux, sudo, users, root

I've added a new user to the group `wheel`. I can ssh into the machine with this user and password and confirm that it belongs to that group:

```
[newuser@xxx.xxx ~]$ groups
newuser wheel
```

But still, if I try to run anything with root permissions:

```
[newuser@xxx.xxx ~]$ sudo ls -lt /root
[sudo] password for newuser:
newuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

And `visudo` confirms that users in the group `wheel` should have these permissions:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

All tutorials say that adding a user to this group should be enough. What else do I have to do?

PS: this is a amazon-linux machine

Answer (score 9):

The `wheel` entry in the sudoers file is commented out, so the group `wheel` has no sudo access at all.

Remove the `#` from the line:

```
%wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Comment: Oh man, I feel so doh!